# What is the quickest way to send some text from desktop\laptop to iPhone?

Tags: file-sharing, notes.app

I usually send emails to myself, but I wonder if there is a better way to share something quickly from my PC\laptop to iPhone.

Comment: Quicker or more easy? What do you use it for?

Answer (score 2):

I use Messages - it is built-in to OSX and you can drag and drop text and images really easily.

Comment: Can you expand on this? Who do you send messages to?

Comment: Myself! That is, either to my iPhone number or my Email address on which my iPhone receives iMessages. I press the `Compose new message` button at the top of `Messages` and fill in the `To` field with my own number or Email address, then I can drag images and drop them onto `Messages`, or paste text into the message window at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use notes or reminders which sync over iCloud. If you are using Windows + iPhone you could try using something like Evernote. It avoids your mailbox from cluttering up, but I doubt it's any quicker than mailing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mavericks, notes has iCloud support.

However, I prefer Evernote. It's available for all major platforms.

Answer (score 0):

### [Scribe](http://usescribe.com/)

I haven't used Scribe, but it does look promising. Install their app on your Mac and its companion app on your iPhone, then press <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> to send the text selected on your Mac to your iPhone. The iOS app keeps a history of sent items too.